# Get instance URL from SAML response (Assertion flow)

Tags: managed-package, saml, apexrest

I am using SAML Assertion flow from external system to access custom REST API in managed package. SAML response shown [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml_assertion_examples.htm&language=th) does not give instance url. Is there anyway to get it? Let me know if any details is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [custom fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_customfields.htm&language=en_US) to the SAML assertion. One of the available fields is `$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_xxx` (where `xxx` represents the Force.com API version - for example, `100` = API 10.0). You could parse the hostname out of one of these URLs to get the instance url.